# Unable to create live tile inside Windows 8 application

Tags: .net, html, windows-8, microsoft-metro

My requirement is to create live tiles inside one of the application pages. But now I am able to create Tiles which reside only in Start screen of Windows 8 tablet.

But I need to create a tile inside an app. 
Environment I am using:

- Visual Studio 2011 Beta
- Its Windows 8 development for Tablets
- Languages used HTML, Js, C# - Its an MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use HUB Tile from wp7 toolkit, which imitate as Live tile.But you need to port HUB Tile Code to Windows 8.