# Using live tiles inside a windows 8 metro application

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to create live tile inside Windows 8 application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279417/unable-to-create-live-tile-inside-windows-8-application)

is it possible to use live tiles inside a page? I know how to configure tiles for start menu, but I don't know how to obtain a similar effect inside my app. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the **LiveTile** control that comes with [Callisto](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto).

Comment: Callisto LiveTile works very well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could create the effect within an application, but the specific mechanism used for the Start screen is not directly available within the context of an application.

[From another post in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10279417/unable-to-create-live-tile-inside-windows-8-application), you may be able to reuse/port code from the Windows Phone 7 toolkit.  There's a number of applications in the Windows Store as well (search for "tile") that provide interfaces for designing tiles, and some may have incorporated similar functionality.

Also [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634759/where-to-start-on-a-tile-view), looks like Telerik may have a solution.