# can you have a live tile within a Windows 8 app?

Tags: windows-8, live-tile

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using live tiles inside a windows 8 metro application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665207/using-live-tiles-inside-a-windows-8-metro-application)

Could be a third party tool provider. If not is there a way to customize it to include live tiles inside the app?How?

Answer (score 0):

The actual "live tiles" implementation is not available inside the App, but you can simulate them and their behaviour.

I think [Callisto](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0526563b-7a48-4b17-a087-a35cea701052) might be what you want, it's really easy to use.